# Did Satoshi ever acknowledge that his name was a pseudonym?

Tags: satoshi-nakamoto, satoshi

I am curious if Satoshi publicly acknowledged that he was concealing his real name, or if he actually claimed that was his real name.

Like the title says, did Satoshi ever publicly acknowledge that his name was a pseudonym?

Comment: @Jedi https://dankaminsky.com/2016/05/02/validating-satoshi-or-not/

Answer (score 5):

This post is the closest to an acknowledgement that is was a pseudonym as can be found:

"I am not Dorian Nakamoto."

http://p2pfoundation.ning.com/xn/detail/2003008:Comment:52186

http://www.forbes.com/sites/kashmirhill/2014/03/06/bitcoin-creator-returns-to-internet-to-say-i-am-not-dorian-nakamoto/#613499a67f43

The above quote was made in response to the Newsweek story falsely outing him as Dorian Nakamoto (birth name Satoshi Nakamota).

http://mag.newsweek.com/2014/03/14/bitcoin-satoshi-nakamoto.html

Comment: But that has nothing whatsoever to do with whether "Satoshi" is a pseudonym, so it's no closer to acknowledging that it's a pseudonym than is the statement "I ate toast for breakfast."

Comment: Right, but it's still the closest we have, unless we all missed something.  Satoshi did a good job at staying anonymous.

Comment: "I am not Dorian Nakamoto" is a sentence that would be true whether or not Satoshi was using his real name or a pseudonym, so this doesn't give me much confidence either way. I think the answer is "No, Satoshi never gave any public indication".